# Has behaviour of Display Templates changed in MVC5 from MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have upgraded from MVC3/Razor to MVC5/Razor.

I have found my Display Template is not reading in the Model value any longer.

The Template is called "MyTemplate":

```
@model System.Object
@{
if (Model !=null)
{
    string.Format("{0:0.00}", Model);
}
else
{
    @:-    
}

}
```

Which is being called by:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mydecimalvalue, "MyTemplate")
```

Model is returning null, when I follow it via the debugger. It used to work fine in MVC3

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}", Model);
```

should be:

```
@(string.Format("{0:0.00}", Model));
```

There must have been a change around this with MVC4 or 5, as it used to work.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Your model type is `System.Object`. Why? What type is `item.mydecimalvalue`, decimal? Why are you checking it for null in your template (if (Model != null))? And what is "returning null"? `Model.ToString()`? What is the `string.Format` line and why is it commented? Please provide some details. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The input type is decimal, although the value could be null in which case I would want to display "-". If there was a value, I want to format the decimal to 2 decimal places. I have corrected my code to be clearer.

Comment: "item.mydecimalvalue" does have a value in the calling view. I have checked this with the debugger and by writing it out. However the value gets converted to null in the template.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it work if you change the model type to `@model System.Decimal?` or `@model System.Nullable<System.Decimal>`?

Comment: @model System.Decimal? does not work. Will try the other.

Comment: No, "System.Nullable<System.Decimal>", does not work.

Comment: It works with string... from the calling view.

Comment: Sorted it... see Edit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you use `Html.FormatValue`, as its the preferred way over `String.Format` in Razor.

```
@model System.Object
@{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        @Html.FormatValue(Model, "0.00")
    }
    else
    {
        @:-
    }

}
```

Reference:

[using string.Format in MVC Razor view page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441584/using-string-format-in-mvc-razor-view-page)

> As you have discovered, it is *possible* to use `String.Format`, but it is a PITA because of the strange (non-intuitive) syntax needed. For that reason, `Html.Format` (a razor extension) is cleaner and IMO, more readable.