# Remove link to document caching in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to append DateTime.Now.Ticks to my link to stop it from caching as I'll be replacing it often. The problem I'm having when I do the code below is that it's adding a Content path in the url.

The original link was:

```
<a target="_blank" href="~/Documents/Data/Acct/MyDocument.pdf">Document</a>
```

This obviously caches the file on the browser so when I overwrite MyDocument.pdf the users don't see that unless they Ctrl-F5. So I changed it to the following:

```
<a target="_blank" href=@string.Format("{0}?t={1}", "~/Documents/Data/Acct/MyDocument.pdf", DateTime.Now.Ticks)>Document</a>
```

This produces a link that looks like: Content/~Documents/Data/Acct/MyDocument.pdf" which obviously doesn't exist because it's adding in Content and keeps the ~. If I remove the ~ I still get Content/Documents/Data/Acct/myDocument.pdf. How do I stop .NET from adding this Content/ to my link?

To add, the page that this link is in, is inside a folder called Views/Content. So I guess that's where it's being called from, but the ~ I assume should go up a level but it's not.

Comment: Use `Url.Content` instead. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439490/1189456

Comment: Do you have your mvc project set to deploy to local IIS instead of IIS Express? (right click project -> properties. Got Web tab.) In local IIS to you have it pointing to a virtual directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a target="_blank" href=@string.Format("{0}?t={1}", "../Documents/Data/Acct/MyDocument.pdf", DateTime.Now.Ticks)>Document</a>
```

If you want to go up a level in your Url use ../ should get rid of the Content